# Could not find file in node_modules folder

Tags: reactjs, ffmpeg

I am working on a ReactJs project. My project folder structure is like below:

```
-node_modules
--ffmpeg.js
---ffmpeg-worker-mp4.js

-src
--components
---AudioRecorder
----AudioRecorder.js
```

In AudioRecorder.js, I am using `ffmpeg.js` plugin. Per their [instruction](https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/#/plugins/ffmpeg.js), I'm setting the code snippet like below:

```
record: {
    audio: true,
    video: false,
    maxLength: 20,
    debug: true,
    // enable ffmpeg.js plugin
    convertEngine: 'ffmpeg.js',
    // convert recorded data to MP3
    convertOptions: ['-f', 'mp3', '-codec:a', 'libmp3lame', '-qscale:a', '2'],
    // specify output mime-type
    pluginLibraryOptions: {
        outputType: 'audio/mpeg'
    },
    // use MP4 encoding worker (H.264 & AAC & MP3 encoders)
    convertWorkerURL: '../../../node_modules/ffmpeg.js/ffmpeg-worker-mp4.js'
}
```

**convertWorkerURL** needs to specify a path inside node_modules folder. I think I specify the correct relative path. But while running the app, I am still hitting the issue that says not found such file.

Oh, I have some override config below.

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  const videojsPlugin = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    videojs: "video.js/dist/video.cjs.js",
    RecordRTC: "recordrtc"
  });
  const videojsAlias = {
    videojs: "video.js",
    WaveSurfer: "wavesurfer.js",
    RecordRTC: "recordrtc"
  };
  config.resolve.alias = { ...config.resolve.alias, ...videojsAlias };
  config.plugins.push(videojsPlugin);
  return config;
};
```

So I am wondering if this is the correct way to do. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see the error? At the build process?

Comment: When loading the js by clicking some button, it show uncaught error in 1st line

Comment: It means it occurs at the runtime. You are using webpack to bundle, aren’t you? If so can I see the config?

Comment: I updated in the question.

Comment: I have found out that your worker script containing Node api such as: `worker_threads`. I'm not sure if it can run on browser though. Basically you can use `worker-loader` to create url to load instead of string like above which doesn't work definitely